# $\binom{2n}{n}$ is divisible by 200, find the minimum value of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\binom{2n}{n}$ is divisible by 200, find the minimum value of n

**My approach:-**

I can't think of a proper structured approach, but I started plugging in the values of n as 5, 10, 15,.... and so on, and was trying to check if I could get a form of $2^{3k} * 5^{2k}$ in the prime factorization, as $200 = 2^3 * 5^2$ .  What should be the way to tackle the problem ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$\cdot$`, which produces $\cdot$, for multiplication.

Comment: Use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), noting that $200 = 2^3 \times 5^2.$  Using the wikipedia article's syntax, and some guesswork, you want $v_5[(2n)!] > 2v_5[(n)!]$, which suggests that $n < 5^2 < 2n$.  Also, as a guess, consideration of $v_2[(2n)!]$ will probably be of only secondary importance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to chop down the cases to check; use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Alternate_form). It lets us write the power of the prime dividing the factorial as,

$$v_p\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\frac{2s_p(n)-s_p(2n)}{p-1}$$

Here $v_p(n)$ is the power of $p$ dividing $n$ and $s_p(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$ when written in base $p$.

In our case we know both $v_2\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=3$ and $v_5\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=2$, but let's just look at the case for $p=2$,

$$3=2s_2(n)-s_2(2n)$$

Notice that in base $2$, multiplying by $2$ doesn't change the sum of digits, just like multiplying by $10$ in base $10$ only appends a $0$ to the end of the number, so we can simplify the right term as,

$$3=2s_2(n)-s_2(n)$$
$$3 = s_2(n)$$

This means the sum of digits is $3$ in binary. Since $1$ is the only digit in binary that means we can start enumerating them and this helps us go in order,

$$111_2=7$$
$$1011_2=11$$
$$1101_2=13$$
$$1110_2=14$$
$$\dots$$

Now we can start writing them in base $5$ to check the other condition,

$$v_5\left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\frac{2s_5(n)-s_5(2n)}{5-1}$$

$$8=2s_5(n)-s_5(2n)$$

For $7=12_5$ so we have $2s_5(12)=2*3=6$ which is smaller than $8$ so no need to work out the second term.

For $11=21_5$ this clearly has the same sum as $7$ did since it's the digits reversed so we can move on.

For $13=23_5$ and $26=101_5$ we have $2s_5(23)-s_5(101)=10-2=8$

So we have found our minimal solution.

Comment: The link which you have provided in the answer has some different formula stated to the one you used here. Is there any alternative, more of an intuitive way too ?

Comment: @Fin27 I have skipped the step of decomposing the binomial coefficient into the three factorials, $\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$. Then using the fact that $v_p(xy)=v_p(x)+v_p(y)$ (and also $v_p(x/y)=v_p(x)-v_p(y)$), I've simplified the formula there.

Comment: Where is the floor function in your formula , which is given in the link ?

Comment: @Fin27 I've updated the link in the answer to link directly to where in the article I'm using it, there is no floor function in that version.